# por que mesmo utilizando width de 100% no input, o input expandiu mais q a div( q possui a class centralizar)

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="nomalize.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css" >
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito' rel='stylesheet'>
    
    
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <header>
        <nav class="menu">
            <a href="#"><img src="img/reddit-brands (4).svg" width="50px"></a>
            <div class="centralizar_logo_titulo">APP Cadastrar despesa</div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="tamanho_container marcador-1">
                <div class="sobre-container">Abertura de Cadastro</div>
                <hr>
                <div class="subtitulos-container ">Tipo</div>
                <div class="centralizar marcador-1">
                    <form>
                        <input placeholder="Tipo" class="texto_container">
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="subtitulos-container">Categoria</div>
                <div class="centralizar marcador-1">
                    <select class="categoria_container">
                        <option value="valor1">Utensilios</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="subtitulos-container">Descrição</div>
                <div class="centralizar">
                    <form>
                        <input  placeholder="Tipo" class="texto_container">
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

  </body>
</html>
```

css ///////////////////////////

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body, ul, li, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-family:"Nunito" ,Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;
    background: rgb(241, 241, 241);
}

header {
    background: rgb(216, 215, 215);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px 2px rgb(155, 155, 155);
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}


.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 15px;
}  

.centralizar_logo_titulo {
    margin: auto 0;
}

/* section 1 */

input.texto_container:visited {
    border: none;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.sobre-container {
    padding: 10px;
}

.tamanho_container {
    width: 100%;
}

.subtitulos-container {
   width: 95%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

.texto_container {
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(129, 128, 128);
}

.centralizar{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 95%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.categoria_container {
    height: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: black;
    border: none;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}

.marcador-1 {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que nesse caso, o problema é devido aos espaçamentos que vem por padrão no navegador, as margens, paddings e tudo mais.

Talvez lhe ajude utilizar o box-sizing.
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Comment: acho q é alguma configuração padrão do input q faz ele ter uma borda e width maior q o select, olha de novo na imagem, parece q ele vazou um pouco da div de 95%

Comment: o select ocupa 100% da div sem vazar.

Comment: já o input, realmente não sei pq, mas ele ultrapassa um pouco da div

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Tente estruturar melhor o seu código HTML;
2. O problema é devido aos espaçamentos que vem por padrão no navegador, ao adicionar "box-sizing: border-box;", problema resolvido!

Para entender melhor sobre box-sizing:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

```css
.abertura_cadastro {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.abertura_cadastro input, .abertura_cadastro select {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: .5rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.abertura_cadastro input, .abertura_cadastro label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="abertura_cadastro">
  <h1>Abertura de cadastro</h1>
  <hr>
  <form action="#">
    <label for="tipo">Tipo</label>
    <input type="text" name="tipo" placeholder="Tipo">
    <label for="categoria">Categoria</label>
    <select name="categoria" id="">
      <option value="utensilios">Utensilios</option>
    </select>
    <label for="descricao">Descrição</label>
    <input type="text" name="descricao" placeholder="Descrição">
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: é isso mesmo, vlwww